# How to configure clang checkers when using flycheck

Tags: emacs, clang-tidy

When using clang checkers via clang-tidy manually, I can add and remove some checks using a  .clang-tidy file.

However when using lsp-mode within emacs, with flycheck activated, clang checkers are run, which is fine, but my .clang-tidy configuration file is not used.
How should I tell flycheck/clangd to ignore some warnings ?

Answer (score 1):

In file `lsp-clangd` there is the variable `lsp-clients-clangd-args`
which can be configured to take into account `clang-tidy` as in below
example:

```lisp
(setq lsp-clients-clangd-args '("-j=4" "--background-index" "--clang-tidy" "--completion-style=detailed" "-log=error"))
```

Check also the file `lsp-clangd` which has some new functions for flycheck and clang-tidy.